# Why is the Release version of my .NET MAUI app not displaying information in a CollectionView while the Debug version is working fine?

Tags: .net, maui

I'm building a .NET MAUI app using .NET 8.0.  I have a model I'm trying to display within a CollectionView.  The build configuration values are default.

When I build the app using the Debug configuration, everything works fine.

[image: Working Debug Configuration]

However, when I build using the Release configuration, none of the information from my model is displayed.

[image: Nonworking Release Configuration]

If I set the BackgroundColor attribute of the CollectionView, the background color of the entire CollectionView changes.  The CollectionView is there, and I can click on an item to select it, but the text and image I expect to see is not visible.

Here is my model:

```cs
public partial class Product : ObservableObject, IIdentifiable
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private Color _backgroundColor;

    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }
    
    public string Description { get; set; }
    
    public string ImageSource { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the initialization code in my ViewModel:

```cs
public partial class SelectProductPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
//...
        public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

        public SelectProductPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, MobileCommanderDatabase database)
        {
            _navigationService = navigationService;
            _database = database;

            Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>()
            {
                new Product()
                {
                    Name = "Swings and Rockers",
                    Category = "Swings",
                    Description = "This is a baby swing",
                    ImageSource = "bb702a.png"
                },
            };
        }
//...
```

Here is my CollectionView:

```xml
<CollectionView Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="0"
                x:Name="ProductCollectionView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}"
                SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding ProductSelectedCommand}"
                SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, Source={x:Reference ProductCollectionView}}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="domain:ProductModel">
            <Grid Padding="10"
                  BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Row="0"
                       Source="{Binding ImageSource}"
                       HeightRequest="150"
                       WidthRequest="150"
                       Aspect="AspectFit"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       VerticalOptions="Center" />
                <Label Grid.Row="1"
                       Text="{Binding Name}"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       VerticalOptions="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Here is part of my project file (I'm not sure what's important to show here)

```xml
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net8.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
        <MtouchLink>None</MtouchLink>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net8.0-android|AnyCPU'">
      <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>True</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net8.0-ios'">
        <CodesignKey>iPhone Distribution</CodesignKey>
        <CodesignProvision></CodesignProvision>
        <ProvisioningType>manual</ProvisioningType>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

What could be causing this issue?

I've searched on Google, Github, and StackOverflow for similar issues, but I can't find anything similar.

I've tried disabling AOT and trimming, but it made no difference.

Comment: Show how you setup your app, get collections etc.

Comment: @LukaszSzczygielek, I added some information. If there is anything specific, let me know what I'm missing

Comment: @JustinKindrix if you set BackgroundColor of CollectionView, can you see it?

Comment: @RiccardoMinato, yes. If I set the BackgroundColor attribute of the CollectionView, the background color of the entire CollectionView changes.  The CollectionView is there, and I can click on an item to select it, but the text and image I expect to see is not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was referencing the wrong data model in my CollectionView's `DataTemplate`.

I had two models that were very similar. One called `Product` and one called `ProductModel`.  They both have some of the same properties, but not all of them.

I updated from this:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:DataType="domain:ProductModel">
```

to this:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:DataType="domain:Product">
```

Now my CollectionView is displaying correctly.